# Geoprocessing service - empty memory after calling

Tags: c#, asp.net, arcgis, esri, arcgis-server

I'm following this sample for ADF libraries

http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET_Server_Doc/developer/samples/Web_Applications/ArcGIS_Buffer_Geoprocessing/ee05ac98-384b-4dbe-b8e3-8d741180dc9a.htm

I'm practically drawing a circle around a point with a geoprocessing service. The radius is about 20 km.

The code is working fine, but the "Clear" routine isn't. Every time I clear the map from the previous data, the memory of the buffer service isn't cleared too and I get this

[image]

The code of the "Clear" routine is the same of the sample, but isn't working:

```
// Clears features from all graphics layers in the resource specified by _graphicsResourceName
protected void ClearGraphics()
{
    // Retrieve the resource and clear its graphics dataset
    ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.DataSources.Graphics.MapResource graphicsMapResource =
        Map1.GetFunctionality(_graphicsResourceName).Resource as
        ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.DataSources.Graphics.MapResource;
    graphicsMapResource.Graphics.Clear();

// This won't work too
GeoprocessingResourceManager1.GetResource(0).ClearState();

// Refresh the resource and copy the map's callback results to the callback results collection so
// the graphics are removed from the map
Map1.RefreshResource(graphicsMapResource.Name);
_callbackResultCollection.CopyFrom(Map1.CallbackResults);
}
```

This should be simple but I can't figure out how to solve this.. the only solution I found is to restart the IIS server which is obviously very bad

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Can you show the code used to draw the circles? (roughly)

Comment: Here is the code: http://nopaste.info/0c123fa03e.html

Look for the ////////////////////////////////////// commented parts to have a rough explanation on what's going on

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough, I meant the code where circles are added to the collection. You are using the `renderer.GetAllSymbols` method to get a list of items. There must be a place where these symbols get created and added to a collection? I haven't used this API, but that's where I would look for.

Comment: I think points are added here:

// Add each point to the feature graphics layer that we're using as input to the GP task
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dataRow in pointElementGraphicsLayer.Rows)
        {
            ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.Geometry.Point adfPoint =
                pointElementGraphicsLayer.GeometryFromRow(dataRow) as
                ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.Geometry.Point;
            featureGraphicsLayer.Add(adfPoint);
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by clearing the jobs' queue

Answer (score 0):

I usually use GraphicsLayerFunctionality.GraphicsDataSet.Tables.Clear();

or

ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.DataSources.Graphics.MapResource myMapResource
 myMapResource.Graphics.Tables.Remove(graphics element);

You are actually dealing with a .NET DataSet